# Dynamic update with method calling to Amazon API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am a beginner in Rails, but I have done a lot of searching on this and can't seem to find something to help me since I am having difficulty breaking down the problem. I have built a working method that requests information about a book given the ISBN from Amazon and would now like to use it to autofill information about the book after a user enters in the ISBN into a form. Here is my method (which is in my listing.rb model file):

```
def self.isbn_lookup(val)
  request = Vacuum.new('US')
  request.configure(
  aws_access_key_id: 'access_key_here',
  aws_secret_access_key: 'secret_access_key_here', 
  associate_tag: 'associate_tag_here' 
)
  response = request.item_lookup(
    query: {
      'ItemId' => val,
      'SearchIndex' => 'Books',
      'IdType' => 'ISBN'
  },
    persistent: true
)
  fr = response.to_h #returns complete hash
  author = fr.dig("ItemLookupResponse","Items","Item","ItemAttributes","Author")
  title = fr.dig("ItemLookupResponse","Items","Item","ItemAttributes","Title")
  manufacturer = fr.dig("ItemLookupResponse","Items","Item","ItemAttributes","Manufacturer")
  url = fr.dig("ItemLookupResponse","Items","Item","ItemLinks","ItemLink",6,"URL")

    return {title: title, author: author, manufacturer: manufacturer, url: url}

  end
```

Here is my controller for now. I am not sure how to make this generic so that the ISBN number relies on what the user enters (it should take in a  value given by the user instead of assuming the @isbn instance variable is always set):

```
def edit
  @isbn = Listing.isbn_lookup(1285741552)
end
```

Here is my _form.html.erb partial where I want to call this ISBN autofill:

```
  <%= form_for(@listing, :html => {class: "form-horizontal" , role: "form"}, method: :get) do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
    <%= f.label :isbn, "ISBN" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <%= f.text_field :isbn, id: "auto-isbn", class: "form-control" , placeholder: "ISBN (10 or 13 digits)", autofocus: true %>
  </div>
</div>
...
<% end %>
```

Finally, here is my JS for what I think should maybe be the start to the AJAX call:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('keyup','input#auto-isbn',function() {
    $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

How do I make it so that when users put in an ISBN, my app will call the isbn_lookup method and then return the information gathered?

Comment: Are you using JQuery? Or just vanilla JS?

Comment: I am using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin, I would create a `lookup` path in your `routes.rb` file. That would look something like:

```
resources :listings do 
  collection do 
    get :lookup
  end
end
```

Which will give you:

```
lookup_listings GET    /listings/lookup(.:format)     listings#lookup
```

Then create the `lookup` action in your `listings_controller.rb`, something like:

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def lookup
    @isbn_lookup_result = Listing.isbn_lookup(params[:isbn])
    render partial: 'isbn_lookup_result'
  end

  ...

end
```

Naturally, this requires that you have a `_isbn_lookup_result.html.erb` file that accesses/uses the values from `@isbn_lookup_result`.

Then, to call this action from your JS, do something like (full disclosure, I use coffeescript, so my plain JS skills are a little rusty):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  @TIMEOUT = null

  $(document).on('keyup','input#auto-isbn',function() {
    clearTimeout(@TIMEOUT)
    @TIMEOUT = setTimeout(function(){
      var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
        url: "listings/lookup",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {isbn: $('input#auto-isbn').val()}
      });
      ajaxResponse.success(function(data){
        # do stuff with your data response
        # perhaps something like:
        $('#isbn-lookup-results-container').html(data)
      });
    }, 500);
  });

});
```

This bit:

```
  clearTimeout(@TIMEOUT)
  @TIMEOUT = setTimeout(function(){
    ...
  }, 500);
```

creates a 1/2 second delay between when your user stops typing and when the ajax function is called. That way, you're not literally doing a lookup on *every* `keyup`, only when the user pauses in their typing.

This bit:

```
var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
  url: "listings/lookup",
  type: 'GET',
  data: {isbn: $('input#auto-isbn').val()}
});
```

is the AJAX call. You can see the new `listings/lookup` path in use. The `data: {isbn: $('input#auto-isbn').val()}` bit gives you `params[:isbn]`, which is used in the `lookup` action.

Then, upon success, you use this bit to do something with your response:

```
ajaxResponse.success(function(data){
  # do stuff with your data response
  # perhaps something like:
  $('#isbn-lookup-results-container').html(data)
});
```

In this case, `data` is the HTML that resulted from the `render partial:` call, so could load it into a `div`.

Comment: This is a great start and exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: Super! Glad to help. In truth, I create custom JQuery plugins to handle stuff like this because I feel it helps me organize my code more effectively. I was tempted to show how to do that, but all my stuff is in coffeescript and I was concerned I'd get plain JS syntax wrong which would only confuse things.

Comment: Will I need a lookup.html.erb file in my views > listings folder?

Comment: You will need a partial. It will need to be called whatever you use in your `render partial:` statement. I suggested `isbn_lookup_result`, but using just `lookup` would probably be more conventional.

Comment: The controller `lookup` action is rendering the partial (see above where it says `render partial: 'isbn_lookup_result'`). In that bit where it says, `ajaxResponse.success(function(data)`, "data" is the rendered partial that is returned by the `lookup` action. And, `$('#isbn-lookup-results-container').html(data)` is where you stick it in the DOM. I just made that last bit up, so you will have to figure out where you *really* want to insert it.

Comment: I understood that right after I posted the comment. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I am on the verge of cracking this one (I stopped working on it for a while). When I type in a valid ISBN in my `input#auto-isbn`, in my console I get the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` beside the url `http://localhost:3000/listings/lookup?isbn=1285740629`. Do you have any idea what could be causing this error?

Comment: That error is in your browser console, I think? You need to look in your rails console to see what's going on there.

Comment: Yeah, it's my browser's console. The Rails console is throwing this error: `ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):`. Does this mean that my @listing variable in my form_for is nil?

Comment: I found the issue. I had to add @listing = Listing.new to my lookup method in my controller.